# Detect the users browser type?

Tags: html

I am using webkit CSS properties that I know will not work in Internet Explorer and other browsers. I want to identify the users browser and if they are not using Chrome or Safari display a message telling them my website isn't supported on their browser.

I know I could just switch a stylesheet based on the browser but I'd rather have them view it on a webkit enabler browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Your site should degrade gracefully in terms of styling - locking people out for using the wrong browser is poor design

Comment: @vogomatix maybe he's coding internal web app.

Comment: @user3574766 what detection do you want to use? is PHP? JS?

Comment: Even an internal site should have the grace to work across the current versions of IE, FF and Chrome. :-), otherwise the instant an IT department decided to change browser, you have to change the site. Having widespread compatibility reduces long terms costs and may only increase the upfront cost slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at whichbrowser, you can get the code from gitgub

http://whichbrowser.net/

https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser

**Edit**

I recomend using a css liabray, which will do all the styling for you so you wont wory about browser problems. A great one to start are:

http://getbootstrap.com/

http://foundation.zurb.com/

Answer (score 0):

this is from a working site. hope this will help you to overcome your problem,

```
<?php
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE) 
            echo 'your error for IE';
    elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE) 
            echo 'your error for firefox';
    elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE) 
            echo 'Google Chrome! you are good to go';
    elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') !== FALSE) 
            echo 'Safari! you are good to go';
            else 
            echo 'error message';
    ?>
```